# What's the best way to write (or rewrite) a math book?

Tags: technical-writing, software, graphics

I've been writing a book that has a fair share of geometric diagrams and equations. However, I am unable to make use of a computer for this and have been maintaining a journal where I manually draw the necessary figures to more easily demonstrate what I'm doing.

However, in the age of the internet, most manuscripts are in electronic format. I'm good with LaTeX but the drawing of geometric figures and especially "constructions" is what prevents me from using a computer.

What's a good approach to this? Write with pen paper first and then transcribe it perhaps? What about the images, just take pictures? For now, I'm planning to make "scanned copies available" for early feedback.

Comment: I see you already have some activity on our sister site [tex.se], but I'm mentioning it here anyway for others who might not be familiar with it and need help with how to express things in TeX and LaTeX.

Comment: I'm quite unfamiliar with it, but I know that TikZ is commonly used in the LaTeX community for producing diagrams and other vector graphics.

Comment: Consider the competing methods of learning such as youtube videos from 3Blue1Brown.

Answer (score 10):

Here are some suggestions of tools you can use to make your drawings:

- [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/): Interactive geometry, algebra, statistics and calculus application, intended for learning and teaching mathematics and science from primary school to university level [[Wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoGebra).
- [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/): Can be used to create or edit vector graphics such as illustrations, diagrams, line arts, charts, logos and complex paintings [[Wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inkscape).
- [Corel Draw](https://www.coreldraw.com/): Vector graphics editor, like Inkscape, but more professional and not free.
- [Tikz](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/TikZ_package): Tool to create graphic elements in LaTeX, but you have to code. ([Examples](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/))

I believe you should try GeoGebra first. It might be entirely suitable for you, and I think it's the easiest to work with.

Looking up video tutorials about these tools might help a lot.

To import the figures to your Latex document, make sure you always save your drawings in a [vector format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics) (such as SVG, EPS or PDF); this format will give you the best quality. 
Also remember to make a copy of each drawing in an editable format (so if you want you can edit it afterwards with whichever tool you used to create it).